# Scraping html data from a web site with <li> tags

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to to get data from this lottery website:
https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/2019

The data I would like scrape is the dates and the winning numbers for 2017 to 2019. Then I would like to convert the data into a list and save to a csv file or excel file.

I do apologize if my question isn't understandable i am new to python. Here is a code I tried, but I don't know what to do after this

```
page = requests.get('https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/2017')    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')    
week = soup.find(class_='win-number-table row no-brd-reduis')    
dates = (week.find_all(class_='win-nbr-date col-sm-3 col-xs-4'))    
wn = (week.find_all(class_='nbr-grp'))
```

I would like my result to be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use BeautifulSoup if there are table tags. It's much easier to let Pandas do the work for you (it uses BeautifulSoup to parse tables under the hood).

```
import pandas as pd

years = [2017, 2018, 2019]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for year in years:
    url = 'https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/%s' %year
    table = pd.read_html(url)[0][1:]
    win_nums = table.loc[:,1].str.split(" ",expand=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    dates = pd.DataFrame(list(table.loc[:,0]), columns=['date'])

    table = dates.merge(win_nums, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    df = df.append(table, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True) 

df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date']) 
df = df.sort_values('date').reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
          date   0   1   2   3   4   5
0   2017-01-04   5   7  36  39  40  44
1   2017-01-07   2   5  14  18  26  27
2   2017-01-11   4  13  16  19  43  51
3   2017-01-14   7   8  10  18  47  48
4   2017-01-18   6  11  17  37  40  49
5   2017-01-21   2  13  17  39  41  46
6   2017-01-25   1  14  19  32  37  46
7   2017-01-28   5   7  30  48  51  52
8   2017-02-01  12  19  26  29  37  54
9   2017-02-04   8  13  19  25  26  29
10  2017-02-08  10  15  47  49  51  52
11  2017-02-11  24  25  26  29  41  53
12  2017-02-15   1   4   5  43  53  54
13  2017-02-18   5  11  14  21  38  44
14  2017-02-22   4   8  21  27  52  53
15  2017-02-25  16  37  42  46  49  54
16  2017-03-01   3  24  33  34  45  51
17  2017-03-04   2   4   5  17  48  50
18  2017-03-08  15  19  24  33  34  47
19  2017-03-11   5   6  24  28  29  37
20  2017-03-15   4  11  19  27  32  46
21  2017-03-18  12  15  16  23  38  43
22  2017-03-22   3   5  15  27  36  52
23  2017-03-25  21  25  27  30  36  48
24  2017-03-29   7   9  11  18  23  43
25  2017-04-01   3  21  28  33  38  52
26  2017-04-05   8  20  21  26  51  52
27  2017-04-08  10  11  12  47  48  52
28  2017-04-12   5  26  30  31  46  54
29  2017-04-15   2  11  36  40  42  53
..         ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
265 2019-07-20   3  35  38  45  50  51
266 2019-07-24   2   9  16  22  46  49
267 2019-07-27   1   2   6   8  20  53
268 2019-07-31  20  24  34  36  41  44
269 2019-08-03   6  17  18  20  26  34
270 2019-08-07   1   3  16  22  31  35
271 2019-08-10  18  19  27  36  48  52
272 2019-08-14  22  23  29  36  39  49
273 2019-08-17  14  18  21  23  40  44
274 2019-08-21  18  28  29  36  48  52
275 2019-08-24  11  31  42  48  50  52
276 2019-08-28   9  21  40  42  49  53
277 2019-08-31   5   7  30  41  44  54
278 2019-09-04   4  26  36  37  45  50
279 2019-09-07  22  23  31  33  40  42
280 2019-09-11   8  11  12  30  31  49
281 2019-09-14   1   3  24  28  31  41
282 2019-09-18   3  24  26  29  45  50
283 2019-09-21   2  20  31  43  45  54
284 2019-09-25   5   9  26  38  41  44
285 2019-09-28  16  18  39  45  49  54
286 2019-10-02   9  26  39  42  47  49
287 2019-10-05   6  10  18  24  32  37
288 2019-10-09  14  18  19  27  33  41
289 2019-10-12   3  11  15  29  44  49
290 2019-10-16  12  15  25  39  46  49
291 2019-10-19  19  29  41  46  50  51
292 2019-10-23   4   5  11  35  44  50
293 2019-10-26   1   2  26  41  42  54
294 2019-10-30  10  11  28  31  40  53

[295 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Is there a way to put the resent draw from buttom ?

Comment: @outkast, What do you mean?

Comment: If you look at the output the recent draw is at the top. is there a way to put to reverse the order

Comment: Aahhh. Ok "recent" not "resent". I was confused by that typo. So you basically want them in order of date, with most recent date on the bottom?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But yes most recent date on the bottom.

Comment: @outkast20, updated it for you. basically just included the date column, converted to a date type, then just needed to sort by date.

Answer (score 1):

Code below create csv files by year with data with all headers and values, in example below will be 3 files: *data_2017.csv*, *data_2018.csv* and *data_2019.csv*.
You can add another year to `years = ['2017', '2018', '2019']` if needed.
**Winning Numbers** formatted to be as **1-2-3-4-5**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/'
years = ['2017', '2018', '2019']

with requests.session() as s:
    for year in years:
        data = []

        page = requests.get(f'https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/{year}')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        rows = soup.select(".win-number-table tr")

        headers = [td.text.strip() for td in rows[0].find_all("td")]
        # remove header line
        del rows[0]
        for row in rows:
            td = [td.text.strip() for td in row.select("td")]
            # replace whitespaces in Winning Numbers with -
            td[headers.index("Winning Numbers")] = '-'.join(td[headers.index("Winning Numbers")].split())
            data.append(td)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
        df.to_csv(f'data_{year}')
```

To save only **Winning Numbers**, replace `df.to_csv(f'data_{year}')` with:

```
df.to_csv(f'data_{year}', columns=["Winning Numbers"], index=False, header=False)
```

Example output for 2017, only Winning Numbers, no header:

> 9-14-16-27-45-51
>  2-4-15-38-48-53
>  8-22-23-29-34-36
>   6-10-11-22-30-45
>  5-10-16-22-26-46
>  12-14-19-34-39-47
>   4-5-10-21-34-40
>  1-25-35-42-48-51

Comment: is there a way i can just get the winning numbers

Comment: Yes you can. Check answer update for code with only Winning Numbers. If you want header in the files use remove `header=False` in `df.to_csv(f'data_{year}', columns=["Winning Numbers"], index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

This should export the data you need in a csv file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
import requests


page = requests.get('https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/2019')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

header = {
    'date': 'win-nbr-date col-sm-3 col-xs-4',
    'winning numbers': 'nbr-grp',
    'jackpot': 'win-nbr-jackpot col-sm-3 col-xs-3',
}

table = []

for header_key, header_value in header.items():
    items = soup.find_all(class_=f"{header_value}")
    column = [','.join(item.get_text().split()) if header_key=='winning numbers'
                       else ''.join(item.get_text().split()) if header_key == 'jackpot'
    else item.get_text() for item in items]
    table.append(column)

rows = list(zip(*table))

with open("winning numbers.csv", "w") as f:
    csv_writer = writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    for row in rows:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

**header** is a dictionary mapping what will be your csv headers to their html class values

In the for loop we're building up the data **per column**. Some special handling was required for "winning numbers" and "jackpot", where I'm replacing any whitespace/hidden characters with comma/empty string.

Each column will be added to a list called **table**.  We write everything in a csv file, but as csv writes one **row** at a time, we need to prepare our rows using the [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (`rows = list(zip(*table))`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise way with bs4 4.7.1+ that uses :not to exclude header and zip to combine columns for output. Results are as on page. `Session` is used for efficiency of tcp connection re-use.

```
import requests, re, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

dates = []; winning_numbers = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for year in range(2017, 2020):
        r = s.get(f'https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/{year}')
        soup = bs(r.content)
        dates.extend([i.text for i in soup.select('.win-nbr-date:not(.blue-bg)')])
        winning_numbers.extend([re.sub('\s+','-',i.text.strip()) for i in soup.select('.nbr-list')])

with open("lottery.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['date','numbers'])
    for row in zip(dates, winning_numbers):
        w.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import io
import re

def main():
    page = requests.get('https://www.lotterycorner.com/tx/lotto-texas/2018')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    week = soup.find(class_='win-number-table row no-brd-reduis')
    wn = (week.find_all(class_='nbr-grp'))
    file = open ("vit.txt","w+")
    for winning_number in wn:
        line = remove_html_tags(str(winning_number.contents).strip('[]'))
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        file.write(line + "\n")
    file.close()

def remove_html_tags(text):
    import re
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return re.sub(clean, '', text)
```

This part of the code loops through the `wn` variable and writes every line to the "vit.txt" file:
    for winning_number in wn:
        line = remove_html_tags(str(winning_number.contents).strip('[]'))
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        file.write(line + "\n")
    file.close()

The "stripping" of the `<li>` tags could be probably done better, e.g. there should be an elegant way to save the `winning_number` to a list and print the list with 1 line.

Comment: how do i print out the output?

Comment: @outkast20 `print(line)` on the line before `file.write(line + "\n")`.